# JQuery Mobile - Link to External Site, can't go back to page with browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I've been having problem with the brower back button and my Jquery Mobile app.

I have attempted to distill the problem to the simplest form.  I have a page with a button on it.  I click the button, the popup appears.  The popup has a link to google on it.  I click the link to google and it works, but when I click the browsers back button, I see the page for a second and then google loads again.  It's like you simply can't go back after leaving the app.

This problem does not occur on PCs or Macs.  It does occur on iPhones and iPads.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>wtf</title> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>


</head> 
<body> 
    <!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="foo">
    <div data-role="content" id="content">  
        <a href="#advisor4" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-close-btn="right" data-inline="true"  data-transition="slidedown" > popup</a>
    </div>      
    <div data-role="popup" id="advisor4" class="advisor popupPage ui-btn-right" data-dismissible="false" data-overlay-theme="e" data-theme="b" ><br/>
        <a class="advisor_button" id="answer-4-26" href="http://google.com" data-history="false" data-ajax="false" rel="external" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-corners="false"> google data-history="false" data-ajax="false" rel="external" </a><br/>
    </div>
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: try to add data-history="false" to popup and check

Comment: if looks like a url problem. When popup is open, it add `#&ui-state=dialog` to url. I've made a solution that works on iphone 5 iso7, safari. try the code here http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ZVhFW/

Comment: @omar on first glance your solution seems to work.  I will accept it (or whatever I'm supposed to do... sorry, noob here)  Can you explain to me WHY it's necessary?  Is this a feature of JQM or a bug or something?

Comment: @amit adding data-history false to the popup didnt seem to help.

Comment: It is not a bug, its for history tracking purpose. Dialogs and popups when are open, their events are pushed into `$.mobile.urlHistory.stack` so when you navigate back/forward using browser's buttons, they are skipped. I've noticed something, when you try to back and the page blinks, hide/close safari (home button) and open it again, then it works. I dont now why..

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I decided that popups were not the way to go for my application and switched to using pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `data-history="true"` instead of `false` in the link.

```
<a class="advisor_button" id="answer-4-26" href="http://google.com" data-history="false" data-ajax="false" rel="external" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-corners="false"> google data-history="true" data-ajax="false" rel="external" </a><br/>
```